# Sort field in Drupal 7

Tags: sorting, drupal-7

I have a content type for which I created a field. I want to sort random field items. My previous topic is [Sort random field items via jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991305/sort-random-field-items-via-jquery).

I want to learn how to randomly sort, via template.php, or other Drupal solution.

How can I randomly sort my field items?

Comment: "or other Drupal solution." << can you suggest what other drupal solutions you would be comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view using contrib [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) that would output the fields that you are interested in sorting.
Now in the view you can select random sort. This option is available in Sort option as "Global: Random".

Comment: I don't wanna use Views module.